# Opinion on what my disk analyzer shows

Tags: debian, filesystems, partition, disk-usage, disk

I recently installed Debian 10 and it's pretty slow on my machine: 12GB memory, 96GB SSD (where the OS runs) and 1TB HDD.

I've only installed anaconda-navigator and some extensions... nothing at all, so I can't understand why it is this slow!

Here's a disk analyzer capture of the HDD:

[image: HDD disk analyzed]

Is it ok to have only 3.5GB used on 977GB with 88151 items (which seems a lot to me)?
And what about the picture? Why is it this much red?

Here's a disk analyzer capture of the SSD:

[image: SSD disk analyzed]

Same questions here. `/usr` seems so full with only 7.7GB on 96GB

I attach also `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.2G  9.6M  1.2G   1% /run
/dev/sdb1        87G  9.1G   74G  12% /
tmpfs           5.9G  115M  5.7G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       916G  4.0G  866G   1% /mnt/data
tmpfs           1.2G   12M  1.2G   1% /run/user/1000
```

PS. Why do I have only 916GB if the hard disk is 1T? I know about the loss from decimal to binary measuring and about hidden features but in my last OS I had like 977GB so I did I lost more space?

This questions may be found useful to newbie like me, so please try to explain me if it's normal or if I have to do something while I install programs or to keep disk clean

Comment: It may be useful to edit the question to include the disk models and also the partition information. All that can be said is that partition sda1 is 916gb.

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough information? What do you mean by slow? Is it in general or at certain times? If the latter, what is being done when it's slow?

Answer (score 0):

That's more than one question you have, so it's hard to answer but let me try.

> Is it ok to have only 3.5GB used on 977GB with 88151 items (which seems a lot to me)?

3,5 GB used by 88151 items, that means on average around 40 kB per item. I don't see any problem with this. And because I don't know what items you have on your data partition, I can't say more on that matter.

> And what about the picture? Why is it this much red?

I assume the program you used is *Disk Usage Analyzer* (formerly *Baobab*). The program chooses one color per directory at each level and starts with red for the first level directory containing the files that use the most data. Since most of your data seems to be below `filesystem`, there is so much red in the image.

Regarding `/usr` on the SSD: below this directory are most of the programs, library and static data like fonts and so on. Therefore this directory contains usually the most data on a new system. Later there can be more data below `/var`, depending on the usage of the system.

> Why do I have only 916GB if the hard disk is 1T?

As @KevinO pointed out in a comment, there is only guessing without information on the disk, the partitions, the used filesystem and whether there is LVM in use and so on.

---

After having tried to answer the questions in your Question, let me say a few words about the question that you didn't pose but that seems to be your real problem:

> I recently installed Debian 10 and it's pretty slow on my machine: 12GB memory, 96GB SSD (where the OS runs) and 1TB HDD.

In most cases the slowness of a machine mostly does not depend on the layout of the data on the hard disk or the SSD. There are many more factors to consider and to get a first picture you can use the program `vmstat` that you run from the command line, for instance in gnome terminal.

On my computer the output looks like this:

```
$ vmstat -w 1 10
procs -----------------------memory---------------------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- --------cpu--------
 r  b         swpd         free         buff        cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs  us  sy  id  wa  st
 0  0            0      1648128       835744      3800720    0    0   143   114  102  244   3   1  96   0   0
 0  0            0      1647748       835752      3801184    0    0     0    36  152  495   1   0  99   0   0
 0  0            0      1648120       835752      3800712    0    0     0     0  163  474   1   1  99   0   0
 2  0            0      1648120       835752      3800712    0    0     0     0  123  341   1   0  99   0   0
 0  0            0      1648120       835752      3800712    0    0     0     0  135  395   1   0  99   0   0
 0  0            0      1648128       835752      3800712    0    0     0     0  129  361   0   1  99   0   0
 0  0            0      1648112       835752      3800712    0    0     0     0  130  396   1   1  99   0   0
 0  0            0      1648120       835752      3800712    0    0     0     0  124  333   1   0  99   0   0
 0  0            0      1647740       835752      3800712    0    0     0     0  243  504   1   0  99   0   0
 0  0            0      1647740       835752      3800720    0    0     0     0  163  400   1   1  99   0   0
```

This command showed some vital parameters of my system in one-second-steps where the first line contained the average information before `vmstat` started.

If my machine were slow, I would look for the following things:

- Is the system swapping - that means does it write memory from RAM to disk and back? The column `swpd` under `memory` shows whether it has swaped out some memory in the past and the columns `si` and `so` under `swap` shows if the system is swapping now, in this second. Swapping means you should have a look what program is "eating" your memory or consider to put in more RAM.
- Does the system write or read much data to/from disk? As disk access is slower then access to RAM, you can investigate which program does so much writing/reading and if this is necessary. Reads from and writes to disk go in blocks, you find the numbers in the columnts `bi` and `bo` under `io`.
- Are there many context switches? A context switch means the CPU stops working in one process and switches to another. A high number of interrupts usually goes along with many context switches. You find the numbers in the columns `in` and `cs` under `system`
- Last but not least you would look where the CPU spends most of the time. The columns below `cpu` give a rough overview: `us` means user space, typically a program computing something, `sy` means time spent running in OS kernel code during system calls, `id` means idle, the percentage the CPU didn't have to do anything, `wa` means waiting for I/O (for instance waiting for disk read and write or waiting for the network), the last column `st` does only apply to virtal machines (VM) and means the time the virtual CPU of the VM is waiting for the real CPU while the hypervisor is servicing another virtual CPU.

So if you want to know why your machine is pretty slow, I would suggest you first look where it is spending its time and then dig a little further how you can remedy this.